# How to create a wind rose with Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics, visualization

I am trying to plot **wind rose** in *Mathematica*, but have no idea how to do this.
[image: Plot]

Any suggestions ?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListPolarPlot.html

Comment: Could be something useful to you here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7867755/879601

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Edit**:

`PolarTicks` uses the built-in option for "Direction".  An earlier version of this answer shows how to manually add `PolarTicks`.

---

The following displays the wind rose on the right (with different data points).  As rcollyer notes, the data points and joining lines can be both achieved in a single use of `ListPolarPlot` through `PlotMarkers->Automatic`.  The `PlotLabel` is from Kuba.

```
r = Table[{2 t Pi/16, RandomReal[{1, 6}]}, {t, 0, 15}];
ListPolarPlot[Append[r, r[[1]]],
  PlotLabel -> "风向图", BaseStyle -> 14,
  PolarTicks -> {"Direction", Automatic},
  Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large]}, PolarAxes -> True, 
  PolarGridLines -> {Table[2 k Pi/16, {k, 0, 15}], Automatic}, 
  PolarAxesOrigin -> {Pi/2, 6}]
```

[image: cardinal directions]

Comment: Why not use `PlotMarkers -> Automatic` alongside `Joined -> True`, then you only have to invoke `ListPolarPlot` once.

Comment: @Kuba  Thanks.  Looks much better now.

Comment: I like this~ Thanks to all~~

Answer (score 44):

**Edit note**: I want to thank to all upvoters, this is really shocking and motivating :). Just to make this answer covering both graphs I've added right graph made with `SectorChart` like I suggested in comments and to not clone David's solution.

```
data = RandomReal[{1, 5}, 16];
```

**Left graph:**
For equally spaced (in angle) measurements it is easier to use `Mesh` for `ParametricPlot`:

```
data2 = ({Cos@#, Sin@#} & /@ Range[0, 15 Pi/8, Pi/8]) data; AppendTo[data2, data2[[1]]];
f = BSplineFunction[data2, SplineDegree -> 1];

g2 = ParametricPlot[(r f[t]), {t, 0, 1}, {r, 0, 1}, BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Black},
                                  Frame -> False, PlotRangePadding -> .2, PlotRange -> 6
                                  MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), Mesh -> (Length[data2] - 2), 
                                  MeshShading -> {White, Black},  Axes -> True, 
                                  Ticks -> None, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads@.07]
```

**Right graph:**

```
data2 = Transpose[{ConstantArray[1, 16], data}];

g1 = SectorChart[data2, PolarTicks -> {"Direction", Automatic}, PlotLabel -> "风向图", 
           BaseStyle -> {15, Bold},  SectorOrigin -> -Pi/16, PolarAxes -> True,
           PolarGridLines -> {Range[Pi/16, 2 Pi, Pi/8], Range[0, Ceiling@Max[data]]}, 
           PolarAxesOrigin -> {(Pi/8 (Position[#, Min@#] &@data-1)])[[1, 1]], 
                               Ceiling@Max[data]},
           ColorFunction -> (Blend["Rainbow", #2] &)]

Row[{g2, g1}]
```

[image]

---

**Old one:** works also for not equally spaced points (in angle).
Why does `ListPolarPlot` has no `Filling->{0,0}` option? :(

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm@Thick,
          Polygon[Riffle[data2, f[0, 0], {2, -1, 3}] /. f -> List],
          White, 
          Polygon[Riffle[data2, f[0, 0], {3, -1, 3}] /. f -> List]
         },
         Axes -> True, PlotRangePadding -> .2, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads@.07,
         Ticks -> None, PlotRange -> 5]
```

[image]

Comment: Next time I upvote one of your answers, I'll wait for at least 3 more updates before doing so :)

Comment: @PinguinDirk now it's not worth it? :( :)

Comment: it was worth it at the beginning already - and now it's better, but I cannot upvote again, see my dilemma? :)

Comment: @PinguinDirk Thank you and don't worry :) I'm glad you find it useful. :)

Comment: @PinguinDirk I'm sorry for the next update :P

Comment: haha, ok, well, for +17 you better get some work done!

Comment: The SectorChart looks very nice.

Comment: @DavidCarraher Thank you, I was inspired by G**gle graphics :)

Comment: Change "data" to "data2" in g1 and add a comment saying that you have to adjust the radial scale manually if you change the data then you'll have my vote as well.

Comment: @Anon Thank you, I've corrected this, also I've made automatic scalling :)

Answer (score 19):

Using `WeatherData` and Kuba's code we can use *Mathematica* to produce an actual [wind rose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_rose) with real data. This is the function I came up with:

```
windRose[city_] := Module[{data, total},
  (* Base the wind rose on thirty years of data, as seems to be customary *)
  data = WeatherData[city, "WindDirection", {{1983, 1}, {2013, 1}}];
  data = Select[
    DeleteCases[data /. {{__}, x_} :> x, _Missing], # < 360 &];
  data = HistogramList[data, {22.5}];
  data = data[[2]];
  total = Total[data];
  data = Transpose[{ConstantArray[1, 16], data/total}];

 SectorChart[data, PolarTicks -> {"Direction", Automatic}, 
 PlotLabel -> city, BaseStyle -> {15, Bold}, SectorOrigin -> -Pi/16, 
 PolarGridLines -> {Range[Pi/16, 2 Pi, Pi/8], Automatic}, 
 PolarAxesOrigin -> {(Pi/8 Position[#, Min@#] &@data[[;; , 2]])[[1, 1]], Max@data[[;; , 2]]}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend["Rainbow", #2] &), PolarAxes -> True]
  ]
```

The argument could be a pair of coordinates, a name of a city or a weather station ID. In the end the wind rose will represent the weather station. If we enter a city, *Mathematica* will choose a weather station in/by that city. So for example:

```
windRose["Chicago"] (* Chicago, Illinois *)
```

[image: Chicago]

```
windRose["Gothenburg"] (* Gothenburg, Sweden *)
```

[image: Gothenburg]

Comment: @Kuba I updated according to your specifications. Much better! Ty.

Comment: Indeed. And again, great idea! ;)

Answer (score 11):

Nothing fancy here, just showing that you can fake Filling in `ListPolarPlot` by creating a `Polygon` (with a vertex at the origin) from each line segment:

```
windrose[data_] := Module[{dat = Append[data, First@data]},
  ListPolarPlot[dat, DataRange -> {0, 2 Pi}, Joined -> True, 
    Ticks -> None, Mesh -> Length[dat] - 2, 
    MeshShading -> {White, Black}, MeshStyle -> None] /. 
   Line[{x__}] :> {Polygon[{x, {0, 0}}], Black, Line[{x}]}]

windrose[RandomReal[{0.3, 1.0}, 16]]
```

[image]