# windrose with data from Excel

Tags: import, excel

How to Import data from excel and use them to Plot windrose instead?

Example, `{{Strength, Angle(degrees)}..}`

```
data = {{11.84,24.70}, {13.64,0}, {14.11,24.70}, {11.92,16.20}, {7.95,337.10}, 
        {8.34,326.60}, {7.85,335.40}, {8.90,6.30}, {10.43,338.40}, {10.36,325.60}, 
        {10.93,332.00}, {14.78,318.20}, {14.30,345.30}};
```

$0$ is `North`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's say you've managed to import the data from excel and you want to transform list:

```
{{strength, angle}...}
```

so it fits the methods from the Q&A: [How to create a wind rose with Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31265/5478). 
There are couple of operations you must do:

```
r = Table[{RandomReal[{0, 20}], RandomReal[{0, 360}]}, {t, 0, 15}]; (*sample data*)
```

- Your list is not sorted with the angle as it need to be for proper joining the points.
- `ListPolarPlot` needs to get `{angle, radius}...}` type of list so in the second step we are doing that.
- last step is only in order to close the line.

---

```
r = SortBy[r, Last]; 
r = {#2 Degree, #} & @@@ r;
AppendTo[r, r[[1]]];

ListPolarPlot[r, BaseStyle -> {Bold, 16}, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
                 PolarGridLines -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/18], Automatic}, 
                 PolarTicks -> {"Direction", Automatic}, PolarAxes -> True, 
                 PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Thick}, 
                 PolarAxesOrigin -> {Pi/2, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image]

Comment: TNX. one more question: how to move lines between dots?

Comment: Up in example we have 16 dot's conected with line's. I don't need line's, I need only dot's. Sorry for stupid question's.

Comment: @StartX just skip the `Joined->True` part :)