# How do I create a radar plot in mathematica?

Tags: plotting

I have been using SectorChart, but it's not quiet what I need. I'm looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26360726#26360726

Comment: Great answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7868926/879601

Comment: closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31257/5478

Answer (score 25):

You can use `ListPolarPlot`.

```
data = {{1, 4, 5, 2}, {3, 5, 1, 1}}; 
cat = {"A", "B", "C", "D"}; 
a = Subdivide[2*Pi, Length[cat]];

 ListPolarPlot[
  Transpose[{a, Flatten[{#, First@#}]}] & /@ data,
  Joined -> True, PolarAxes -> True,
  PolarTicks -> {Transpose[{Most@a, cat}], Automatic},
  PolarGridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The only *extra* bit is to close the polygon by including the first data point at the end of the plot series.  This is what `Flatten[{#, First@#}]` is doing.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

This aims to deal with multidimensional axes with normalized data.

```
fun[l_, lab_, mx_, gr_, col_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{n = Length[lab], v, m, p},
  v = #/mx & /@ l;
  m = Map[
    Function[x, 
     MapIndexed[{2 Pi (#2[[1]] - 1)/n, #1} &, x]~Join~{{0, x[[1]]}}], 
    v];
  p = ListPolarPlot[m, PolarAxes -> {True, True}, 
      PolarAxesOrigin -> {#, 1}, Joined -> True, 
      PolarGridLines -> {{#, Thick} & /@ 
         Range[0, 2 (n - 1) Pi/n, 2 Pi/n], False}, 
      PolarTicks -> {Table[{2 Pi j/n, 
          Style[lab[[j + 1]], 
           FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Style]]]}, {j, 0, n - 1}], 
        Automatic}, PlotStyle -> col, 
      Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]] & /@ 
    Range[0, (n - 1) 2 Pi/n, 2 Pi/n];
  Legended[Show @@ p, LineLegend[col, gr]]
  ]
```

`l` is the values of dimensions in lists
`lab` is label of dimension and axis label
`mx` is maxima for dimensions to allow normalization
`gr` is label of groups
`col` is color of plot
`opts` various options

This is rather ugly and not "cleaned up" wrt to arguments but I post in hope it motivates.

A toy example of movies (with none in mind) and dimensions: "coherent plot", "visual effects", "enjoyment", "likelihood of recommending", "acting". Each scored out of 10.

```
fun[{{1, 2, 3, 2, 1}, {4, 5, 3, 3, 3}}, {"coherent plot", 
  "visual effects", "enjoyment", "likelihood of recommending", 
  "acting"}, {10, 10, 10, 10, 10}, {"Movie 1", "Movie 2"}, {Red, 
  Green}, TicksStyle -> {12, Blue}, FontColor -> Red, FontSize -> 12, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {1.5, 0.2}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

This is just illustrative and can be modified as desired to achieve whatever visualization and aesthetic goals are required. Apologies for the silly toy and silly colour scheme (and of course errors).

Answer (score 5):

As of *v12.2*, we have a built-in [`RadialAxisPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RadialAxisPlot.html).

Comment: (+1) Didn't know V12.2 is out!

Comment: It is documented... https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RadialAxisPlot.html

Answer (score 2):

- There is a Wolfram Function Repository (WFR) function [`RadarChart`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RadarChart).
- There is a package for making radar plots/charts, called ["RadarChart.m"](https://github.com/catrasca/RadarChart). (Not the same implementation/author as WFR's linked above.)

  - [GitHub link](https://github.com/catrasca/RadarChart)
  - [Community link](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/762950)