# Insets around a clock

Tags: graphics, charts, inset

I have this code to generate a clock-like diagram:

```
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 2], Line[{{0, 0.8}, {0, 1.2}}], 
Arrow[Reverse@Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, -Pi, Pi/2, 0.1}]], 
Table[Line[{{2 Sin[θ],2 Cos[θ]}, {(2 - 0.2) Sin[θ], (2 -0.2 ) Cos[θ]}}], {θ, 0,2 π, π/9}],
 Text[Style[0, Large], {0, 0.6}]}]
```

[image]

It has 18 tick marks. I also have this code to generate 18 LinePlots:

```
AllData= Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/DsVfiMZN", "Table"];
datai=Table[data[20*i] =AllData[[All,2*i+1;;2*i+2]], {i, 0,17}];
ploti=Table[p[20*i]=ListLinePlot[data[20*i],PlotRange->{{0.5,7.5}, 
{0,0.6}},Axes->False,PlotStyle->{Black}],{i,0,17}];
GraphicsRow[ploti,ImageSize->1000]
```

[image]

Each one of the 18 plots is indexed as an angular position, so p[0] refers to 0 degrees, p[20], 20 degrees and so on. How can I place each plot around the clock at the correct tick marks? Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Somewhat related: [(31257)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31257/121), [(31347)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31347/121), [(104639)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104639/121), [(166247)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/166247/121)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can also arrange the lines on a circle like a pie chart:

```
ClearAll[llpOnCircle]
llpOnCircle[dt_, colors_, filling_: True, r1_: 1, r2_: 3/2, scale_: 1] := 
  MapIndexed[{Darker @ colors[[#2[[1]]]], 
     Line[(r1 + #[[2]] scale) {Cos[#[[1]]], Sin[#[[1]]]} & /@ #], 
     If[filling, {Opacity[.5], Lighter@colors[[#2[[1]]]] , 
       Polygon[Join[((r1 + #[[2]] scale) {Cos[#[[1]]], Sin[#[[1]]]} & /@ #), 
        (r2 {Cos[#[[1]]], Sin[#[[1]]]} & /@ Reverse[#])]]}, {}]} &, dt];
```

***Examples:***

We first pre-process the input data to partition and re-scale the columns:

```
columns = Range @ 36;
angles = Partition[Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, Length[columns]/2], 2, 1];
rescaled = AllData[[All, #]] & /@ Partition[columns, 2];
rescaled[[All, All, -1]] = Rescale[rescaled[[All, All, -1]]];
rescaled[[All, All, 1]] = MapIndexed[
   Rescale[#, MinMax[AllData[[All, 1]]], angles[[#2[[1]]]]] &, rescaled[[All, All, 1]]];
```

and combine the graphics primitives from OP's first code block

```
g1 = {Circle[{0, 0}, 2], Line[{{0, 0.8}, {0, 1.2}}], 
   Arrow[Reverse@Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, -Pi, Pi/2, 0.1}]], 
   Table[Line[{{2 Sin[θ], 2 Cos[θ]}, {(2 - 0.2) Sin[θ], (2 - 0.2) Cos[θ]}}], 
     {θ, 0, 2 π, π/9}], 
   Text[Style[0, Large], {0, 0.6}]};
```

with lines produces by `llpOnCircle`:

```
SeedRandom[777];
colors = RandomColor[18];
labels = RandomWord[18];
legend = SwatchLegend[colors, labels];


Legended[Graphics[{g1, llpOnCircle[rescaled, colors, True, 2.1, 2.6, .5]}, 
  ImageSize -> Large], legend]
```

[image]

```
Legended[Graphics[{g1, llpOnCircle[rescaled, colors, False, 2.1, 2.6, .5]}, 
  ImageSize -> Large], legend]
```

[image]

Change the fifth argument of `llpOnCircle` from `2.6` to `2` to get filling below the lines:

```
Legended[Graphics[{g1, llpOnCircle[rescaled, colors, True, 2.1, 2, .5]}, 
  ImageSize -> Large], legend]
```

[image]

Use `colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@columns];` to get

[image]

**Update:** An alternative approach using `SectorChart` with a custom `ChartElementFunction`:

```
ClearAll[cEF]
cEF = {Line[MapThread[# {Cos@#2, Sin@#2} &, {#[[2, 1]] + #3[[1]], 
       Subdivide[#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], Length[#3[[1]]] - 1]}]]} &;

yvals = rescaled[[All, All, -1]]; 
SectorChart[{1, Max@yvals} -> # & /@ yvals, SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 3}, 
 Epilog -> Inset[Graphics @ g1, {0, 0}, Automatic, Scaled[1/2]], 
 ImageSize -> 600, ChartStyle -> (ColorData[97] /@ Range[18]), 
 ChartElementFunction -> cEF, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[MapIndexed[Style[#, 14, ColorData[97][#2[[1]]]] &, labels], 
   "RadialOutside"]]
```

[image]

You can control the radial width of the sectors using a combination of values in the second part of the `SectorOrigin` option setting and in the last argument of `Inset`. You can use the option `SectorSpacing` to separate sectors:

```
SectorChart[{1, Max@yvals} -> # & /@ yvals, 
 SectorSpacing -> {.5, 0}, 
 SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 4}, 
 Epilog -> Inset[Graphics@g1, {0, 0}, Automatic, Scaled[4/5]], 
 ImageSize -> 600, 
 ChartStyle -> (ColorData[97] /@ Range[18]), 
 ChartElementFunction -> cEF]
```

[image]

To add edges for a more clear separation of sectors, replace `cEF` with `cEF2` where

```
ClearAll[cEF2]
cEF2 = {Line[MapThread[1.02 # {Cos@#2, Sin@#2} &, {#[[2, 1]] + #3[[1]], 
       Subdivide[#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], Length[#3[[1]]] - 1]}]], 
    FaceForm[], 
    ChartElementData["Sector"][{#[[1]], {.95 #[[2, 1]], 1.02 #[[2, 2]]}}, ##2]} &;
```

[image]

**Update 2:** Play with options settings for [`SectorOrigin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SectorOrigin.html) to control the starting positions and orientation of sectors. For example:

```
Row[SectorChart[{1, Max@yvals} -> # & /@ yvals, 
    SectorOrigin -> #, 
    Epilog -> Inset[Graphics@g1, {0, 0}, Automatic, Scaled[1/2]], 
    ImageSize -> 400, ChartStyle -> (ColorData[97] /@ Range[18]), 
    ChartElementFunction -> cEF2, 
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"SectorOrigin -> ", #}]] & /@ 
  {{{Pi/2, "Clockwise"}, 1.5}, {{Pi/2, "Counterclockwise"}, 2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, but there is something strange with the insets. They are in the wrong positions. If you look at the one at the position zero, it seems to be replaced by the one at 80 degrees. How can I remove all the filling?

Comment: @Rodrigo, updated with a version that makes filling optional. Re positions you can control the starting position and direction in the pre-processing stage using, for example, `angles = Reverse @Partition[Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, Length[columns]/2], 2, 1]` to get the parts oriented clockwise; and `angles = RotateRight[#, 5] &@Reverse@Partition[Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, Length[columns]/2], 2, 1]` to  have the fifth part positioned at 0 and the parts oriented clockwise.

Comment: Now it looks correct. Even with filling set as false, the lines still keep the random color. Can that be turn off as well?

Comment: @Rodrigo, you can use `colors = Table[Black, 18]` to make all lines `Black`.

Comment: With the second example, using cEF2, the insets are still in the wrong position. Also, if I turn off the legends, the insets move outwards.

Comment: @Rodrigo, please see update 2.

Comment: Great. Just one more thing. In update 2, what attribute changes the height of the insets? I mean the width of the outer circular crown. I would like to make it just a bit narrower.

Comment: @Rodrigo, you can play with combinations of the second part of `SectorOrigin` and the last argument of `Inset`. For example, try `SectorOrigin -> {{Pi/2, "Counterclockwise"}, 10}` and  `Epilog -> 
 Inset[Graphics@g1, {0, 0}, Automatic, Scaled[.75]]`.

Comment: I've noticed something after coming back to this question. If you look at Update2 on the left, the plots seem to be flipped horizontally. The blue graph at the position 0 seems to be a mirror image of the original p[0] plot. I can't figure out why.

Comment: @Rodrigo, try replacing `Subdivide[...]` in `cEF` with `Reverse @ Subdivide[...]`?

Answer (score 15):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

AllData = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/DsVfiMZN", "Table"];
datai = Table[
   data[20*i] = AllData[[All, 2*i + 1 ;; 2*i + 2]], {i, 0, 17}];

ploti = Table[
   p[20*i] = ListLinePlot[data[20*i],
     PlotRange -> {{0.5, 7.5}, {0, 0.6}},
     Axes -> False,
     PlotStyle -> Black,
     ImageSize -> 36],
   {i, 0, 17}];

Graphics[{
  Circle[{0, 0}, 2],
  Line[{{0, 0.8}, {0, 1.2}}],
  Arrow[Reverse@Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]},
     {t, -π, π/2, 0.1}]],
  Table[Line[{{2 Sin[θ], 2 Cos[θ]},
     {(2 - 0.2) Sin[θ], (2 - 0.2) Cos[θ]}}],
   {θ, 0, 2 π, π/9}],
  Text[Style[0, Large], {0, 0.6}],
  Inset[p[20*#], 2.35*
      {Sin[20*#*Degree], Cos[20*#*Degree]}] & /@ 
    Range[0, 17]}]
```

[image]