# How to set the Arrowheads style in a figure with broken vertical axes

Tags: plotting, graphics, style

I am trying to combine three separated curves into a same figure. The codes are inspired by [another post and answers here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8241/generating-a-broken-or-snipped-axis-in-listplot?lq=1).

Codes:

```
snip[pos_] := 
  Arrowheads[{{Automatic, pos, 
     Graphics[{BezierCurve[{{0, -(1/2)}, {1/2, 0}, {-(1/2), 0}, {0, 
          1/2}}]}]}}];

data1 = {{1, 1.1}, {2, 1.5}, {3, 0.9}, {4, 2.3}, {5, 1.1}};
data2 = {{1, 1001.1}, {2, 1001.5}, {3, 1000.9}, {4, 1002.3}, {5, 
    1001.1}};
data3 = {{1, 8001.1}, {2, 8001.5}, {3, 8000.9}, {4, 8002.3}, {5, 
    8001.1}};

getMaxPadding[p_List] := 
 Map[Max, (BorderDimensions@
        Image[Show[#, LabelStyle -> White, Background -> White]] & /@ 
      p)~Flatten~{{3}, {2}}, {2}] + 1

p1 = ListPlot[data1, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, 
   AxesStyle -> {{Arrowheads[.035], Directive[Black, 12]}, {snip[1], 
      Directive[Black, 12]}}, PlotRangePadding -> .2, 
   ImagePadding -> {{50, 5}, {15, 5}}, AspectRatio -> 1/3];

p2 = ListPlot[data2, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, Axes -> {False, True}, 
   AxesStyle -> {{None}, {snip[0], Directive[Black, 12]}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> .2, ImagePadding -> {{50, 15}, {5, 5}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/3];

p3 = ListPlot[data3, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full, 
   PlotStyle -> Magenta, Axes -> {False, True}, 
   AxesStyle -> {{None}, {snip[0], Directive[Black, 12]}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> .2, ImagePadding -> {{50, 15}, {5, 5}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/3];

output = Column[{p3, p2, p1} /. 
   Graphics[x__] :> 
    Graphics[x, ImagePadding -> getMaxPadding[{p1, p2, p3}], 
     ImageSize -> 500]]
Export["testBrokenAxiesFigure.png", output]
```

and output are:

[image]

1. How can I add an additional arrow to the vertical axis of the figure?
2. And how can I change the `single Bezier curve separation symbol` (at 1002.5 on the vertical axis) into a `double Bezier curve symbol` like that at about 2.5 on the vertical axis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have to modify `snip`a little bit:

```
ClearAll[snip]

snipCurve = Graphics[
  {BezierCurve[{{0, -(1/2)}, {1/2, 0}, {-(1/2), 0}, {0, 1/2}}]}
];

snip[pos_?NumberQ, primitive_Graphics: snipCurve] :=  snip[
  {pos}, primitive
];

snip[pos_List, primitive_Graphics: snipCurve] := Arrowheads[ 
  {Automatic, #, primitive} & /@ pos
];

snip[pos_List, primitives_List] :=  Arrowheads[
  Flatten /@ MapThread[{Automatic, ##} &, {pos, primitives}]
];
```

Now it will accept a list of positions as well as list of primitives that should be used. For convenience a default `Arrow` can be put by `{}`.

SO, `AxesStyle` for `p2, p3` (*p1 without changes*) respectively should be:

```
AxesStyle -> {
  {None}, 
  {snip[{0, 1}], Directive[Black, 12]}
}

AxesStyle -> {
  {None}, 
  {snip[{0, 1}, {snipCurve, {}}], Directive[Black, 12]}
}
```

[image]

---

> Thank you very much! Is it possible to change the size of the vertical axis arrow?

Don't have time to prepare handy and general patterns for `snip` but we can change something in the last definition:

```
snip[sizes_List, pos_List, primitives_List] := Arrowheads[
   Flatten /@ Transpose[{sizes, pos, primitives}]
]
```

Now, let's use this in *yspec* for `p3`:

```
AxesStyle -> {
  {None}, 
  {snip[{Automatic, .1}(*here*), {0, 1}, {snipCurve, {}}], Directive[Black, 12]}
}
```

and *xspec* for `p1` can be changed directly:

```
AxesStyle -> {
  {Arrowheads[.1(*here*), .035], Directive[Black, 12]}, 
  {snip[1], Directive[Black, 12]}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible to change the size of the vertical axis arrow? ---I noticed there is a package [SciDraw](http://scidraw.nd.edu/) for scientific drawing, if such functions here can be generalized and combined into [SciDraw](http://scidraw.nd.edu/), that would be great.

Comment: BTW @Kuba, I also noticed in one of [your answers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31257/how-to-create-a-wind-rose-with-mathematica/31265#31265), you posted "风向图" as a `PlotTitle`, are you a native speaker of such language?

Comment: @user6043040 I will try to address your question about size in the incomming edit. No, I'm from the very center of Europe, that probably was the wind rose phrase I've googled to match OPs needs.